# How to throw the error if the mobile no is not existing in user table using trigger

Tags: trigger, workflow

I need to update owner(Standard Field) name on custom page(Buyer) using Referral Id(mobile of Lead owner)..

The Referral Id(Mobile No) already present in user details.

For example the buyer is created by me but i put the Referral Id was my manager mobile no.After created the Buyer i need to updated owner as my manager name not mine.If the Referral Id is not user table i need to throw the error and dont create. Now it show my name and the lead created.

I tried the following trigger

```
    trigger LeadAssignmentTrigger on Broker__c (before insert,before update) 
    {
        List<Broker__c > leadsToUpdate = new List<Broker__c >();
        for (Broker__c broker: Trigger.new)
        {     
            if (broker.Referral_ID__c!= NULL)
            {
                String str = broker.Referral_ID__c;
                Integer ln = str.Length();
                String likeStr = '%'+str.subString(ln-10, ln-7)+'%'+str.subString(ln-7, ln-4) +'%'+ str.subString(ln-4);

                // Find the sales rep for the current zip code
                List<User> zip = [select Id from User
                                       where MobilePhone Like : likeStr];

                // if you found one
                if (zip.size() > 0) 
                {    
                    //assign the lead owner to the zip code owner
                    broker.OwnerId = zip[0].Id; 
                    leadsToUpdate.add(broker);
                }
            } 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `addError` method like:

```
        List<Broker__c > leadsToUpdate = new List<Broker__c >();
        for (Broker__c broker: Trigger.new)
        {     
            if (broker.Referral_ID__c!= NULL)
            {
                String str = broker.Referral_ID__c;
                Integer ln = str.Length();
                String likeStr = '%'+str.subString(ln-10, ln-7)+'%'+str.subString(ln-7, ln-4) +'%'+ str.subString(ln-4);

                // Find the sales rep for the current zip code
                List<User> zip = [select Id from User
                                       where MobilePhone Like : likeStr];

                // if you found one
                if (zip.size() > 0) 
                {    
                    //assign the lead owner to the zip code owner
                    broker.OwnerId = zip[0].Id; 
                    leadsToUpdate.add(broker);
                }
                else
                {
                    // Throw Error
                    broker.addError(' Error Message to Display/Log');
                }
            } 
        }
```